# Google Calendar and Google Cloud Storage with service account?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'am writing a Golang app that will read calendars events in Google suite and after some processing output some content to a json file stored on Google Storage.

Is there any simple way of accessing these 2 things using the same credentials, preferably a Service Account to avoid Oauth Token URL asking at startup ?

I did find about Delegation (as explained here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) but i'm not sure this is the right way to go and it will success for storage as well.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Any help on this topic ?

Comment: where are you running the code, in GAE? Are you using the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go) for Go?

Comment: @Iñigo: No it's running on my own infrastructure on a little program i wrote : https://github.com/webofmars/oncall-buddy-finder. And yes i used the both Golang Gooogle Cloud lib and Google API lib